# Shaping qrcode opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently building for fun a small app based on c++ and opencv.
The purpose of this app is to create a qrcode and then to "smooth" it using opencv functions.

The problem is that i'm not having the results i was expecting. I've used so far

```
Mat element = getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
morphologyEx(paternMat, paternMat, MORPH_CLOSE, element, Point( -1, -1 ), 3 );
```

Of course also tried with MORPH_OPEN, cv::erode, cv::dilate ... but i still can't manage to have the result i want.

My question, is simple, on [this example](http://qrcode.selectionpro.fr/www/qrcode/), how can i manage to go from the first qrcode, to the second one, using opencv functions ...

Many thanks ;)

**EDIT :**

medianblur worked as expected, and many thanks for your fast answers.

I would have a last question. I've edited my example with another qrcode, and i was wondering how could i manage to obtain that with opencv. I've tried various combination, but noone would actually work.

I request one last time your generous help ;), here's the example : [this example](http://qrcode.selectionpro.fr/www/qrcode/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried the **cv::Smooth** function?

Here you have some details: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=smooth#smooth

Answer (score 0):

Look into the function `blur`, `gaussianBlur`, `medianBlur`, `bilateralFilter` in OpenCV.

Refer: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html

Comment: Thank you very much, medianblur worked perfectly.
However, i would like to know if you could help me with the second one i'm trying to obtain (see my edit post).
Thanks again for your help !!